# `jekyll build` has error but gitlab ci still continues

Tags: jekyll, gitlab-ci

I have a Jekyll website running on Gitlab Pages, and one of my pages contained an error.
This error is found and reported by Jekyll, but the website is still deployed, just without that page.

In Gitlab's job output I see the following:

```
$ jekyll build -d public
...
Bundle complete! 5 Gemfile dependencies, 29 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux-musl]
Configuration file: /builds/TheOddler/mjb/_config.yml
            Source: /builds/TheOddler/mjb
       Destination: /builds/TheOddler/mjb/public
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
             Error: YAML Exception reading /builds/TheOddler/mjb/_work/immaculate.md: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 1
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 1.104 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
Uploading artifacts for successful job 00:09
Uploading artifacts...
```

So it shows `Error: YAML Exception ...` but then still continues as if everything is OK.

The job in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this:

```
build-jekyll:
  stage: build
  image: jekyll/jekyll:4.2.0
  script:
  - jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Why does this happen? And is there a way to make the process fail, or at least report this as a warning so I know something went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to "Why does this happen?" is probably that Jekyll, dispite the error in the output, returns with exit code 0.

Comment: @slauth That would make sense. Only strange that Jekyll does that.

Comment: I agree. Others seem to have [strumbled upon this as well](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5257).

Comment: @slauth Interesting. A real shame how that thread went down though. Might need to report a similar issue again now then. Tanks!

Comment: I just by accident read about a Jekyll option `--strict_front_matter`. You could try that.

Comment: @slauth That does seem to help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: great, I turned the solution into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Jekyll, dispite the error in the output, returns with exit code 0. You could try to add the `--strict_front_matter` option to let Jekyll return a non-zero exit code.